# Erlang treasure hunt

Tags: erlang

I have the following task:

> Create a simple treasure hunt game.
>
> Create a two-dimensional array of integers 10 by 10.  In a random
>   position in the array store the number 1.  repeat  Get the user to
>   enter coordinates where they think the treasure is.  If there is a 1
>   at this position display ‘success’.  Until they find the treasure

Instead of using arrays I used lists:

```
-module(hunt).
-export([start/0]).
start() -> 
    X = [[12,1,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],[12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],[12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],[12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],[12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],[12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],[12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],[12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],[12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],[12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5]],
    loop(X).
loop(X) ->
    Inputs = io:get_line("Enter the coordinates"),
    {A,_} = string:to_integer(string:substr(Inputs,1,2)),
    {B,_} = string:to_integer(string:substr(Inputs,3,2)),
    erlang:display(A),
    erlang:display(B),
    case get(X,A,B) of
        1 -> io:format("You did it!");
        _ -> io:format("Try again"), loop(X)
    end.
get(List,A,B) ->
    ghelper(List,A,B).
ghelper(List,A,B) -> ghelper(List,A,B,0,0).
ghelper([H|Tail],A,B,N,M) -> 
    case N == A of
        true -> ghelper(second,H,B,M);
        false -> ghelper(Tail,A,B,N+1,M)
    end.
ghelper(second,[H|Tail],B,M) -> 
    case M == B of
        true -> H;
        false -> ghelper(second,Tail,B,M+1)
    end.
```

Is there a way to improve this further? I know I could probably make a function to randomly generate a 2D array (represented by lists here), but apart from that, is there anything I could improve?

Answer (score 3):

Even though your code works I have some comments regarding Erlang style and naming conventions:

1. Spaces after commas and empty lines between function definitions make the code a lot more readable.
2. Helper functions that do the actual work are usually named with the `do_` prefix. Instead of `ghelper` I would have named that `do_get`.
3. Using [`lists:nth`](http://erldocs.com/current/stdlib/lists.html?i=0&search=lists:nth#nth/2) could greatly simplify your code. The standard library includes a lot of useful functions, I try to always check if there is an existing function for what I want to do and only if there's none then I implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I read your code and it works. I have some suggestions though, that could apply to a more complex example.

- I think that you should dig in the libraries in order to use existing functions. In my opinion it helps for readability and generally
  it saves some line of code: less work, less bugs, more time to spend for the user.
- In this example, the code interacts with the user, its is a case where the "let it crash" erlang habit does not suit the usage,
  I suggest you to use the io_lib to read the expected input from the user, and ind him the syntax in case of error (You could also have
  a give up option).
- I prefer to use different function heads (pattern matching) rather than case statement to deal with recursion stop condition,
  for example the code

  ghelper([H|Tail],A,B,N,M) -> 
      case N == A of
          true -> ghelper(second,H,B,M);
          false -> ghelper(Tail,A,B,N+1,M)
      end.

may be replaced by:

```
ghelper([H|Tail],A,B,A,M) -> 
        ghelper(second,H,B,M);
ghelper([H|Tail],A,B,N,M) -> 
        ghelper(Tail,A,B,N+1,M).
```

and even better using explicit names:

```
get_row([H|Tail],A,B,A) -> 
        get_cell(H,B,1); // start at 1 to give the same result as lists:nth/2
get_row([H|Tail],A,B,N) -> 
        get_row(Tail,A,B,N+1).
```

But this version fails if the user enters a bad syntax, or out of boundary coordinates, I propose this version
which checks the user input. The answer decoding and checking are straight, half of the code is for the user friendliness

```
-module(hunt).

-export([start/0,start/2]).

start() -> start(10,10).
start(MAXCOL,MAXROW) ->  
    loop(generate(MAXROW,MAXCOL),MAXROW,MAXCOL).

loop(X,MAXROW,MAXCOL) ->
    Inputs = io:get_line("Enter the coordinates : "),
    case check(io_lib:fread("~d~d",Inputs),X,MAXROW,MAXCOL) of
        true -> io:format("got it~n");
        _ -> io:format("try again~n"),
                 loop(X,MAXROW,MAXCOL)
    end.

check({ok,[A,B],_},X,MAXROW,MAXCOL) when A > 0, B > 0, A =< MAXCOL , B =< MAXROW ->
    lists:nth(A,lists:nth(B,X)) =:= 1;
check(_,_,MAXROW,MAXCOL) -> 
    io:format("Invalid answer , please give an answer formatted as : \"X Y\"~nwhere 0 < X <= ~p, 0 < Y <= ~p~n",
        [MAXCOL,MAXROW]).

generate(MAXROW,MAXCOL) ->
    random:seed(erlang:timestamp()),
    Xs = random:uniform(MAXCOL),
    Ys = random:uniform(MAXROW),
    F = fun(X,Y) when X == Xs, Y == Ys -> 1; (_,_) -> random:uniform(10) + 1 end,
    Res = [[F(X,Y) || X <- lists:seq(1,MAXCOL)] || Y <- lists:seq(1,MAXROW)],
    io:format("~p~n",[Res]),
    Res.
```

compile and test it

```
1> c(hunt).
{ok,hunt}
2> hunt:start(8,3).
[[6,11,9,8,7,6,8,7],[3,4,2,2,4,4,5,6],[2,8,2,6,5,8,1,11]]
Enter the coordinates : hello!
Invalid answer , please give an answer formatted as : "X Y"
where 0 < X <= 8, 0 < Y <= 3
try again
Enter the coordinates : 1 2
try again
Enter the coordinates : hello
Invalid answer , please give an answer formatted as : "X Y"
where 0 < X <= 8, 0 < Y <= 3
try again
Enter the coordinates : 8 3
try again
Enter the coordinates : 1 1
try again
Enter the coordinates : 8 4
Invalid answer , please give an answer formatted as : "X Y"
where 0 < X <= 8, 0 < Y <= 3
try again
Enter the coordinates : 7 3
got it
ok
3>
```

Answer (score 1):

- You should clean up your output strings, since currently they print without any punctuation or newlines and so make it hard for the user to read them.
- Avoid using `get` as a function name, since there's already a [`get` function in the `erlang` module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#get-0), and experienced Erlang programmers will initially assume you're using that function rather than your own local function. I renamed your function to `element`.
- You don't specify whether the coordinates you're requesting from the user are 0-based or 1-based. Running your program shows they're 0-based, which is fine, but you need to be clear about that.
- There's really no need for a function named `ghelper`; you could instead just use different clauses for the `element` function. Or better yet, just use [`lists:nth/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#nth-2) as described in another answer and get rid of all the other clauses entirely.
- Use [`io:fread/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fread-2) to get the coordinates from the user, since it can read the inputs and convert them to integers in one step.
- You need to check that the values the user enters are within range.
- Use more descriptive variable names.

Here's a revised version that takes this advice into account:

```
-module(hunt).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    Values = [[12, 1,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5], [12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],
              [12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5], [12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],
              [12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5], [12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],
              [12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5], [12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5],
              [12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5], [12,13,14,15,16,22,11,11,2,5]],
    io:format("Guess the 0-based coordinates of the value 1.\n"),
    loop(Values, length(Values), length(hd(Values))).

loop(Values, RowMax, ColMax) ->
    {ok, [Row,Col]} = io:fread("Guess the row and column, comma-separated: ",
                               "~d,~d"),
    case {Row < RowMax, Col < ColMax} of
        {true, true} ->
            case element(Values, Row, Col) of
                1 ->
                    io:format("Congratulations, you found the 1 at (~w,~w)!\n",
                              [Row, Col]);
                _ ->
                    io:format("The 1 is not at (~w,~w), please try again\n",
                              [Row, Col]),
                    loop(Values, RowMax, ColMax)
            end;
        _ ->
            io:format("(~w,~w) is out of range, please try again\n", [Row, Col]),
            loop(Values, RowMax, ColMax)
    end.

element(Values, Row, Col) ->
    lists:nth(Col+1, lists:nth(Row+1, Values)).
```

And here's example output from compiling and running it:

```
$ erlc hunt.erl
$ erl -noshell -s hunt -s init stop
Guess the 0-based coordinates of the value 1.
Guess the row and column, comma-separated: 3,4
The 1 is not at (3,4), please try again
Guess the row and column, comma-separated: 10,11
(10,11) is out of range, please try again
Guess the row and column, comma-separated: 0,1
Congratulations, you found the 1 at (0,1)!
```